# What is the best way to get a configuration variable in PHP

Tags: php, app-config

Each server (Dev, QA, Prod) has a different IP address and URL. I would like to write code so that it can pull that information (the URL for the particular server I am running the code on) from a configuration file and store it in a variable.

Preferably I would like to avoid having to read the information from a file on subsequent requests since the information should not be changing often.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `$_SERVER` array to get the current server details

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Specifically, `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` and `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` (IP + hostname of the host/virtual host the script's running in).